# Use persistence.xml declared in different module

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

I'm using different separated modules in my app ..

jpa-module : contains the JPA entities and the persistence.xml

rest-module : where I'm using JAX-RS services and Hibernate to persist the data ...

I'm injecting the entitymanager using Guice, however I got an error (if I do not put the persistence.xml under the rest-module)

```
2016-09-07 22:09:06.704:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@72c28d64{/services,file:///Users/rest-module/target/rest-module-1.0-SNAPSHOT/,STARTING}{../rest-module/target/rest-module-1.0-SNAPSHOT}
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named local_persist_unit
```

Here is the content of my persistence.xml :

```
  <persistence-unit name="local_persist_unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>

            <!--PostgreSQL-->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.metamodel.generation" value="disabled"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
```

Any Idea why Hibernate was not able to find the persistence.xml file ??

Answer (score -1):

When maven multi module project, where we have different modules for REST, Service, DAL or n layers, we can define the persistence unit in different module.

You can check here in  [Example : Github project](https://github.com/sveluri/product-catalogue/tree/master/dal/src/main/resources/META-INF) where persistence.xml is defined in dal layer irrespective of REST layer.

Make sure the classpath recognizes by adding the xml to

```
dal/src/main/resources/META-INF
```

How ever, there would be dependency hierarchy,

```
REST -> Service -> Dal
```